# Исчезающий текст в textarea, как реализовать?

Tags: html

Имеется поле для ввода сообщения, хочу сделать чтоб текст который в ней стоит по умолчанию при начале ввода исчезала или перестала быть активной. Как в ВК, допустим на стене у собеседника в поле ввода стоит "Написать сообщение", после того как вы кликните туда, то его содержимое исчезает. Не додумаюсь как это сделать( с событием onclick), а так же с запретом изменение размера окна ввода.

```
<textarea  cols='23' rows='4'    name='text'>Введите здесь ваше сообщение</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QLV27/

html

```
<textarea placeholder="Ваш текст"></textarea>
```

css

```
textarea{    
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, да так =) А без CSS это нельзя было бы сделать?

Comment: так замещающий текст без css, добавьте атрибут placeholder="Здесь ваша подсказка"

Comment: >resize: none;

Зачем?!? ЗАЧЕЕЕЕМ!?! ЗАЧЕЕЕМ ВЫ ТАК ДЕЛАЕТЕ?!?!?!

Comment: @MrClon, чтобы не ломали дизайн

Comment: у меня в проекте был textarea - не стандартный (дизайнер выделился) + нужна верстка пиксельперфект - а растягивать textarea за спец маркер в макете не было - я сначало этот маркер не убрал, но заказчику не понравилось, пришлось убрать. В данном случае можно убрать - это дело каждого.

Comment: Оптимально - resize: vertical;
Растягивание по вісоте в редких случаях портит дизайн

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите через js, Вам нужны события [onfocus](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onfocus) и [onblur](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onblur).
Примерный код HTML:

```
<input type='text' value='Что Вы ищете?' onfocus="clearSearchInput(this)" onblur="resetSearchInput(this)">
```

Примерный код JS:

```
var searchText="Что Вы ищете?";
function clearSearchInput(input) {
    if(input.value===searchText){input.value="";}
}
function resetSearchInput(input) {
    if(input.value===""){input.value=searchText;}
}
```

Можете ещё дописать изменение цвета текста в функциях или любые другие действия.